# SQL Server 2019 and Transparent Data Encryption - Intermittent (silent) Error Log Messages

Tags: sql-server-2019, transparent-data-encryption, error-log

I recently migrated a SQL Server 2017 TDE database to SQL Server 2019 CU4.  I was browsing the Error Log and noticed intermittent messages about

```
An error occurred while processing log encryption. The process was recovered automatically. No user action is required.
```

These messages are always preceded by

```
Error: 1222, Severity: 16, State: 55.
```

And

```
Lock request time out period exceeded.
```

I found [FIX: TDE encrypted Databases go in suspect state during the recovery phase when you restart SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3197631), where it discusses a fix that has been back-ported to previous versions of SQL Server.

From that post

> Assume that you have a Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) encrypted
> database on an instance of Microsoft SQL Server. When you restart the
> instance of SQL Server, you may receive a lock time-out error that
> resembles the following: Starting up database . Error:
> 1222, Severity: 16, State: 55. Lock request time out period exceeded.
> Error: 9016, Severity: 21, State: 7. An error occurred while
> processing the log for database . The log block could
> not be decrypted. Then, the database will go in a suspect state.You
> can get the database back online by using Emergency Mode. You won't
> encounter corruption.

I'm not in the situation where my instance is being restarted, but it seems this *fix* is similar to what I am experiencing.

While I appreciate the process being automatically recovered, I'm concerned why the error is even showing up in the error log.

I also have an almost identical instance in the same migration scenario from SQL Server 2017 to 2019 that is NOT experiencing these errors.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue with a new 2019 enterprise edition as well which popped up today.

Comment: Installed latest CU8 and still the same.